# Enumeration of symbols in grammatical expressions or vertices in tree graphs

Tags: reference-request, notation, trees, formal-grammar, type-theory

I have expressions (type of a function) like e.g.

$$f:(A\to B)\to C \to (D\to E)\to F.$$

(Where I understand $A\to B\to C$ as $A\to (B\to C)$, in case that is relevant.)

There might be information associated with each symbol/type "$A,B,...$" as well as with each of the arrows "$\to$". Given the expression above, I would like to refer to these symbols, but not by stating the symbol but in terms of $f$. Like for example I might want to say "$E$ is $\mathbb{R}$." and would naively express this like "$f_{9}$ is $\mathbb{R}$." where I just made up the convention that $f_i$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ symbol in the type of $f$. I could equally well refer to the two objects "arrow-symbol" and "non-arrow-symbol" seperately, so that in this case $E$ would be the $5^{\text{th}}$ non-arrow symbol. Or I could take into account that e.g. "$(A\to B)\to C$" is totally differently "stacked" than "$A\to (B\to C)$" and hence use an enumeration which climbs down that syntactic tree.

> Is there a standard or canonical way to refer to the items of an expression (logic, type, any syntactic expression really)? More generally one might ask if there is some canonical enumaration principle for trees.

I'm concerend with types of functions here, but the question can be understood as a more general reference request for standard notation.

I also don't know about normal forms of types, which might be relevant to make the enumeration more robust in case there are more ways to do it (robust in that the enumeration would not by dependend of the particular way the type is stated).

Comment: It might be worth looking at [De Bruijn index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) and [De Bruijn notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_notation), then refer to particular type symbols, for example, via the stacked indexes of the corresponding lambda term.

Comment: As for canonical enumerations, you can go with a pre-, in- or post-order. Also any algebraic type such as $T[\alpha] = \alpha + T^2[\alpha]$ would give you some enumeration. Finally, you can refer to nodes by a path from root, e.g. `LRRLRL` or something similar.

Comment: @dtldarek: The De Bruijin seems to be just a rewriting which gives me no obvious way of refering to a particular symbold within the expression. I don't understand the second post, except for the LRRLRL-thing.

Comment: Those are orderings derived from [DFS tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings). The given algebraic type is a type of a tree, by numbering the operators/constructors you get _some_ enumeration method (this is usually similar to 'path from root' method, but has different motivation and might be easier or harder to deal with, depending on the context).